# Create an InstancedBufferGeometry from existing geometry in Three.js

Tags: three.js

**How can you create an InstancedBufferGeometry from existing geometry?**

I have a tube I've created as a buffer geometry. I'd like to create 100 instances of it, but unsure of the correct syntax with the latest Three.js version. [InstancedBufferGeometry docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=instance#api/en/core/InstancedBufferGeometry)

This works in an example from an old version of three (v0.107.0), but no longer.

```
const curve = new THREE.LineCurve3(
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1)
);

let baseGeom = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(curve, 25, 1, 8, false);
let instanceGeo = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(baseGeo);

const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "rgba(100,0,50,1)"
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(instanceGeo, material;
```

Codesandbox in case you want to try it out - see CarLights.js for the use of InstancedBufferGeometry:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wip-akira-lights-d4h7k?file=/src/CarLights.js

Comment: An alternate way: `mesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( geometry, material, count );`.

Comment: @WestLangley - so interestingly, trying that too in the codesandbox linked above, and that doesn't render anything as well. Seems like this should be a pretty 'hello world' use of it with a basic geo and mat, curious what is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

This way it shows 100 instances of TubeGeometry:

```js
import * as THREE from "three";

class CarLights {
  constructor(scene, options = { nPairs: 100 }) {
    this.scene = scene;
    this.options = options;

    const curve = new THREE.LineCurve3(
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1)
    );

    const geo = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(curve, 25, 1, 8, false);
    const geoInstance = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(geo);
    geoInstance.instanceCount = 100;

    const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: "rgba(100,0,50,1)",
      onBeforeCompile: shader => {
        shader.vertexShader = `
          attribute vec3 instPos;
          ${shader.vertexShader}
        `.replace(
          `#include <begin_vertex>`,
          `#include <begin_vertex>
            transformed += instPos;
          `
        );
        //console.log(shader.vertexShader);
      }
    });

    let instPos = [];
    let vec3 = new THREE.Vector3();
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      vec3.random().subScalar(0.5).multiplyScalar(20);
      instPos.push(vec3.x, vec3.y, vec3.z);
    }
    geoInstance.setAttribute("instPos", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instPos), 3));

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geoInstance, mat);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
}

export default CarLights;
```